# How To Add Items To A Multiline Select And Show Them In The View

Tags: elm

In my **model** I have a field that stores a `List` of syllables:

```
type alias Model =
{   freeSyllables : List FreeSyllable
    ...
}
```

The syllable looks like:

```
type alias FreeSyllable =
{   syllable : String
,   usage : Usage
}
```

I want to bind the string in each **syllable** to a `select` in my `view`:

```
select [ size 20, style [ ("width", "70px") ] ] []
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display each syllable as an `option` of a `select`, you'll need `option` function from `Html` module:

```
import Html exposing (Html, beginnerProgram, text, option, select)
import Html.Attributes exposing (style, value)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)
```

Then just map `freeSyllables` to options with `value` and `text` equal to `syllable` or to something else (`value` is what you get as an input, `text` is what displayed on the screen to select from)

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    let
        syllableToOption : FreeSyllable -> Html Msg
        syllableToOption freeSyllable =
            option [ value freeSyllable.syllable ] [ text freeSyllable.syllable ]
    in
            select [ onInput SetSyllable ] (List.map syllableToOption model.freeSyllables)
```

When an option is selected an event (for example `SetSyllable`) is triggered. Thus, you'll need something like this in the `update` function:

```
type Msg
  = SetSyllable String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        SetSyllable syllable ->
            model
```

Comment: Thank you, but how does Elm treat the concept of two way data binding?

Comment: According to The Elm Architecture, the `view` doesn't directly update the `model` and `model` doesn't directly update the `view`. Every update goes through the `update` function. `update` function receives a message (for example `onInput` event for an input) and should return the updated `model`, which then is displayed on the view.